# How can I identify which observations are used in a linear regression?

Tags: r

I am having trouble running `predict` after running a linear regression because I cannot figure out which X variables are actually included in the linear regression.

Let's say I run the model:

```
model1 <- lm(outcome ~ employee + shape + size + color + I(color^2) 
  data = data)
```

The number of observations identified in the regression output is 224605.
When I try to run predict like so:

```
test = data.frame(y = predict(model1), x = data$employee)

Error in data.frame(y = predict(model1), x = data$employee) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 224605, 233262
```

I thought I could get the correct number of observations like so:

```
> test = na.omit(data, cols = all.vars(model1))
> nrow(test)
[1] 207256
```

but this still does not yield the correct number of observations.  Is there a direct way to grab the observations actually being used by linear regression?

Comment: `all.vars()` doesn't seem to do anything to a linear model. I just get `character(0)` out. But that's the right idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `model.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
df[c(3, 5), 1] <- NA
df[7, 2] <- NA

df
#             x           y
# 1  -0.6264538  1.51178117
# 2   0.1836433  0.38984324
# 3          NA -0.62124058
# 4   1.5952808 -2.21469989
# 5          NA  1.12493092
# 6  -0.8204684 -0.04493361
# 7   0.4874291          NA
# 8   0.7383247  0.94383621
# 9   0.5757814  0.82122120
# 10 -0.3053884  0.59390132

fit <- lm(y ~ x, df)

model.frame(fit)
#              y          x
# 1   1.51178117 -0.6264538
# 2   0.38984324  0.1836433
# 4  -2.21469989  1.5952808
# 6  -0.04493361 -0.8204684
# 8   0.94383621  0.7383247
# 9   0.82122120  0.5757814
# 10  0.59390132 -0.3053884
```

Comment: and if you want to get the row numbers of the original dataset "data"
``row.names(model.frame(fit))``
so that
``data_used <- data[row.names(model.frame(fit)),]``
might be useful

Answer (score 2):

Missing observations are omitted by default. If a row has an `NA` for any of the variables used in the model, it will be omitted. See `?lm` and the `na.action` section for details.

You can run `na.omit(data[c("outcome", "employee", ..."color")])` to get the data frame with the omitted variables (put all the columns in your formula into the `na.omit()`. You can also pull it out of the model object, `model1$model` is the data frame used for model fitting (with missing values omitted).

You may also want to look into the `broom` package for tidying up your model. `broom::augment` is a nice way to add predictions back to the original data.